# Is it possible to use add-a-wire with my current configuration to add a C-Wire?

Tags: thermostat, cooling, thermostat-c-wire

I only have four wires: Red, Blue, Yellow, and Green. My old thermostat jumps the R to RC and leaves C empty.

I have a new thermostat that wants 5 wires, but I don't have C. I am not sure what the circuit diagram is here, so I don't know if it's possible to make a new configuration that will give full functionality.

Here is my configuration:

Rc   (jumper to red) 
R    Red
Y    Blue
C    -
W    White
G    Green

What does add-a-wire do anyway? There is no extra wire so I would have to tear up my wall to run a new wire. I don't want to sacrifice independent fan control. What is the easiest way I can rewire this for a new thermostat?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ADD-A-WIRE™ Owners Manual](http://www.venstar.com/Support/Manuals/ACC0410ManualRev1.pdf), you should be able to use the product to achieve your goal.  I've never used this product, and do not endorse it in any way. I have no idea if it actually works, I'm simply going on the claims made by the manufacturer.

This is the diagram from the manufacturer.

> [image]

This is how I'd wire it up.

[image]

- `R` and `W` stay the same, at both the furnace and the thermostat.
- Switch the `BLUE` wire to `C`, at both the furnace and thermostat.
- Connect the ADD-A-WIRE™ device in the furnace as described in the installation instructions, but connect the `BLUE` wire from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device to the `GREEN` wire in your cable.
- Connect the `BLUE` wire from the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y', to the `GREEN` wire from your cable at the thermostat.
- Finally, connect the `GREEN` wire from the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y' to the `G` terminal of the thermostat, and the `YELLOW` wire from the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y' to the `Y` terminal of the thermostat.

<sub>***WARNING:** Use of this product is at your own risk. I have never used this product, and will take no responsibility for any damage it may cause. Be sure to read all manufacture documentation before using this device.*</sub>